# Group WPF Grid using Radio Buttons

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have List of class contains element category and family
categories can contain different families I want the user using Radio buttons to select the grouping column for example when he chooses group by category .. if the category has one family only a row is created with category name and in the family column this family name is shown .. if it has more than one family multiple one row is created showing category name then the word varies ..

as shown in these two pictures

[Group By category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCJ2U.png)
[Group By family](https://i.stack.imgur.com/280Oo.png)

I tried WPF groups and filters but nothing gives me the functionality I want